# I want to Deserialize the Json-File and output it's data

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net, json-deserialization

**I thought I would understand Json.NET now a bit
but unfortunately not. Can somebody help me with that**

 I am trying to show data from the json-file in the Console

 (Error:CS1061 | List has no definition for "title" | file:Programm.cs | line: 23)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var todos = CObject();
            if (todos != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(todos.title);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static List<Todos> CObject()
        {

            string localfile =
                @"C:\g\todos.json";

            if(File.Exists(localfile))
            {
                var todos =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Todos>>
                        (File.ReadAllText(localfile));

                return todos;
            }

            string urlfile = new WebClient().DownloadString(
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");


            if (File.Exists(urlfile))
            {
                var todos =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Todos>>
                        (File.ReadAllText(urlfile));

                return todos;
            }

            return null;
        }
     
    }
}
```

This is the Todos.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Todos
    {
    public byte userId { get; set; }
    public ushort id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The json-file looks something like that:

```
[
 {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 19,
    "title": "molestiae ipsa aut voluptatibus pariatur dolor nihil",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 20,
    "title": "ullam nobis libero sapiente ad optio sint",
    "completed": true
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you meant `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Todos>>(urlfile)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CObject` returns a List (btw naming the class `Todo` would probably be better for later understanding). You can iterate over the list and each item inside should have a title property. But a list has not.

```
foreach(var item in todos) {
  Console.WriteLine(item.title);
}
```